# "Unable to load realm mapping info from SCDynamicStore" error followed by KrbException

Tags: hadoop, osx-lion

I am trying to build my app locally and get the following error:

```
    **Unable to load realm mapping info from SCDynamicStore**
2012-12-03 18:13:23.910 java[1172:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'JavaNativeException', reason: 'KrbException: Could not load configuration from SCDynamicStore'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff919c30a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff894ea3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91a57229 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   JavaNativeFoundation                0x0000000104260c3f JNFCallStaticVoidMethod + 213
    4   libjava.jnilib                      0x00000001042b0169 Java_sun_security_krb5_SCDynamicStoreConfig_installNotificationCallback + 450
    5   JavaNativeFoundation                0x0000000104263182 JNFPerformEnvBlock + 86
    6   SystemConfiguration                 0x00007fff9327f12d rlsPerform + 116
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91942101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91941a25 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91964dc5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff919646b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
    11  java                                0x000000010394c843 java + 18499
    12  java                                0x000000010394c29a java + 17050
    13  java                                0x0000000103949a98 java + 6808
    14  ???                                 0x0000000000000008 0x0 + 8
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
/bin/sh: line 1:  1172 Abort trap: 6           /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar /opt/pose/core/target/surefire/surefirebooter7934174390972693745.jar /opt/pose/core/target/surefire/surefire5395873653031509674tmp /opt/pose/core/target/surefire/surefire_01183106063530311982tmp

Results :

Tests run: 305, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.RuntimeException: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.close(ForkClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:695)
    at.........
```

This started happening after I upgraded my system to OS X 10.8.2. I also changed my hadoop-env.sh to have this value:

> export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm=OX.AC.UK -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc0.ox.ac.uk:kdc1.ox.ac.uk"

and also updated the hbase-env.sh to have:

> export HBASE_OPTS="-ea -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="

I also installed the latest Xcode and all of no use.

Comment: I have the same problem when I use JDK 7. I get rid of it when I use JDK6 (at least in the terminal)

Answer (score 0):

export MAVEN_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm=OX.AC.UK -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc0.ox.ac.uk:kdc1.ox.ac.uk"